# SaaS platform homepage UX: Getting Around vs. Insights Feed vs. Informational

Tags: dashboard

I'm trying to decide between three options for a professional SaaS desktop platform that keeps track of a brand and its competitors.

1. Getting Around - showing links to all your configured abilities. For example 'list of your define brand and competitors and links to their monitors'.
2. Insights Feed - showing a feed of the main changes that happened recently that might interest you and link to the relevant ability. For example: Brand X was 145% more popular during the recent 7 days compared to all-time.
3. Informational - showing tables and graphs that summarizes what happened recently, and allows you to drill down deeper. For example a table and graph with the popularity of each configured brand in the past week, month and all-time.

The end results might be some sort of hybrid combination, but I'm still trying to identify what will be the main leading element and build around it. I have a feeling (2) is less popular in the realm of SaaS professional platforms, but was wondering if there are good examples where this was proven as a good solution for such a target audience. Any advice on the route I should take to decide between the three would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the main aim of your application?What exactly will the end user be interested in like the most common information they would look for in your site?

Answer (score 1):

I have a hard time trying to understand what your product is in this case, but I will attempt at an answer anyway.

There are plenty of great SaaS products that try to compare you against your competitors.  Some of the top companies out there are extremely successful because of one reason. They are FOCUSED.  These companies don't try to give you every option they think you may want or need. They tell you what you want or need. If you need something else, then they will try to push you towards another product they own that is similar or simply say you aren't a customer we are focusing on now.

Most people think the focused approach is crazy and wonder how they can be successful, but the point is that because it is so focused, it allows the product to evolve and be completely catered to that group.  Take [Chartbeat](https://chartbeat.com/) for example.  They are a terrific company, but if you are in publishing and want to know anything and everything about your audience, Chartbeat doesn't work. This is why they created NewsBeat.

Back to your question.  If you can keep the information the user is presented to at the bare minimum but focused on topics you know your primary market will want and need, then you can push all the other functionality through various means. For example, you can allow users to identify their top competitors. Your product may scan their site, their social networks and SEO. You can show that comparison at a high level, but as they want to drill down and understand demographics you can start breaking down by demographics, segments, etc.

As I said, hard to know what you are looking for in an answer without providing more details on your product.